# React + Formik + Yup async validation

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Formik + yup 
validation with .test() triggers on change on every field

example: 
i have a validation schema:

```js
const schemaValidation = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup.string().email().required()
    .test( // it runs even if previous validation failed!
      'checkEmailExists', 'email already taken.',
      // it triggers on every onBlur
      email => { console.log('email registration runs') return Promise.resolve(true)}
    ),
  other: yup.string().required()
     .test(
      'checkOthers', 'error', 
      val => {console.log('other validation runs'); return Promise.resolve(true)}
    )
})
```

render function on my react component looks like:

```js
...
render () {
 return(
  <Formik
    validateOnChange={false}
    validateOnBlur={true}
    initialValues={{
      name: '',
      email: '',
      other: ''
    }}
    validationSchema={schemaValidation}
    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  >
    {(props) => (
    <Form>
      <div className="field">
        <Field className="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <ErrorMessage name="email" />
      </div>

      <div className="field">
        <Field className="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
        <ErrorMessage name="name" />
      </div>

      <div className="field">
        <Field className="input" type="text" name="other" placeholder="Other"/>
        <ErrorMessage name="other" />
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
 )
```

so after every single field changed I receive messages from all .test() validators in console:

```
email registration runs
other validation runs
```

versions:
react: 16.13.1
formik: 2.1.4
yup: 0.28.4

Comment: Oh wow, it's been a year, I have the similar feature like yours. But I'm out of luck. I can't seem to find any right answer. `yup` also didn't accept validation chain. Have you find your own solution now? @Justillusion

Comment: Are find any solution for this I am also stuck in the same @Justillusion

Comment: I'm also stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default formik validates after change, blur and submit events. Your code disables validation after change events with `validateOnChange={false}`. In order to only validate on submit events, try setting `validateOnBlur` to `false` too.

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#when-does-validation-run
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#validateonblur-boolean

Comment: validateOnBlur is behavior i want. 
but i wanna to validate only field i had edit, not whole form

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, try the following approach directly on your Field components: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#validate

Comment: i wrote validator for single Field whom return Promise, but it still work the same.
no matter which field trigger onChange, single validator runs.

Comment: "The function will respect the validateOnBlur and validateOnChange config/props specified in the <Field>'s parent <Formik> / withFormik."

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone in 2022,

I understand a lot of `formik` has changed over the years - but thought I share a relevant solution that's using `touched` property, feel free to peek at https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-54204827-llvkzc.

And also shared for another StackOverflow question here,  [React Native Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204827/react-native-form-validation/73320681#73320681).

In summary, it's basically used like below (with `yup` outside of this snippet), to decide whether to show (if any) input validation errors:

```js
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          email: "",
          password: ""
        }}
        validationSchema={LoginSchemaA}
        onSubmit={(
          values: Values,
          { setSubmitting }: FormikHelpers<Values>
        ) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            setSubmitting(false);
          }, 500);
        }}
      >
        {({ errors, touched }) => (
          <Form>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Field
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="john.doe@email.com"
              type="email"
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email ? (
              <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.email}</div>
            ) : null}

            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <Field id="password" name="password" type="password" />
            {errors.password && touched.password ? (
              <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.password}</div>
            ) : null}

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

And as `package.json` reference, below are the defined versions:

```json
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    ...
    "yup": "0.32.11"
  },
```

Hope this helps for those on these mentioned `formik` and `yup` versions above!